# Node.js - Write after end error

Tags: android, node.js, raspberry-pi3

I have setup a TCP server using Node.js which is running on my Raspberry pi 3. I communicate with the server using an android client (Code from [this][1] tutorial). I get a response from the server only when the client connects to connects to it for the first time.

When I try to make another request to it, the request is received and processed but while sending the response I get an error saying: write after end.

Code(Edited):

```
var net = require('net');
var devList = [];
var dev_msg; 

function serverCallback(socket){
    console.log("-----------------------------------------------------");

    socket.setNoDelay(true);

    socket.on('data', function(data){
        var req = data.toString();

        console.log(req);

        InitSystems(socket);
    });

    socket.on('error', function(err){
        console.log(""+err);
    });

    socket.on('end', function(){
        console.log("Write end");
    });
}


function InitSystems(socket){
  socket.write("Message 1: Hi!");
  socket.end();

  //After 2nd request from client
  socket.write("Message 2: Event has successfully taken place!"); //<-- Error here
  socket.end(); 
}

console.log("Server now running!");

var netServer = net.createServer(serverCallback);
netServer.listen(6969);
```

**EDIT:**
Android code:

```
try{
            socket = new Socket("192.168.1.13", 6969);

            socket.setSoTimeout(24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
            socket.setKeepAlive(true);

            dOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            dOut.writeUTF("INIT");
            dOut.flush();

            ba = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
            buffer = new byte[1024];

            int bytesRead;
            is = socket.getInputStream();

            while((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1){
                ba.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                res += ba.toString("UTF-8");
            }

            Log.d(TAG, res);

            connStat = true;
        }catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
        } catch(SocketException e){
            Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e){
            try{
                Thread.sleep(2100);
            }catch (Exception e1){

            }finally {
                connStat = false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
        }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's a lot going on there. Can you reduce your code down to the part that's breaking? Often this will point directly to the problem. Also, please format your code so it's easily readable. Your code editor should be doing this for you. If not, you can use an [online beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/).

Comment: Do you realize you have a `setTimeout()` that will close the socket in 3 seconds if some condition was not previously met on the socket?

Comment: @jfriend00 I have tried it without setTimeout()  but I still get the error

Comment: @RyanWheale posted the edited code

Comment: Ah thanks - like I said, the problem code easily revealed itself. Writing an answer now...

Comment: `socket.end()` half closes the socket so you can't send more data after calling `.end()`.  Don't call `.end()` if you intend for the socket to stay open.

Comment: @jfriend00 Then how do I send the response back to the server without using end? My android client only receives the data after .end() is called.

Comment: `socket.write()` sends the data on its own.  You don't have to do anything else. Please read [the doc](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_end_data_encoding).  It's all explain there.

Comment: @jfriend00 My android client only receives the data after .end() is called.

Comment: That is caused by something else then and would be a different question and would need to disclose your android code.   `.end()` is half closing the socket so that's why you can't write again.  FYI, this would probably be easier with a higher level library such as webSocket or socket.io (I'd personally use socket.io since it has auto-reconnect logic built in).

Comment: You can do some debugging on the `socket.write()` by examining the return value and by supplying a callback to `.write()` so you can see when exactly the data is written to the socket and whether it is telling you the buffer is full.

Comment: Conceptually, I don't see why you're calling `InitSystems()` on every incoming data packet on the socket.  That just seems like the wrong logic or misleading naming.  At least call it `processPacket()` or something more meaningful and something that connotates an ongoing process rather than a one-time thing.

Comment: @jfriend00 I had posted my actual code initially, this is just the broken down version of it. And I have tried socket.io but the android client can't seem to connect to the tcp server.

Comment: A socket.io client has to connect to a socket.io server, not a plain TCP server.  Similar, a webSocket client has to connect to a webSocket server.

Comment: So, the answer to the question you originally asked is that `.end()` half closes your socket so, of course, you can't write again to that same socket.    Remove the `.end()` and that problem goes away.  You really ought to start over with a new question that is about why your Android client isn't receiving the data.  That's a completely different question and needs some debugging on both side of things to see what is going on.  Stack overflow does not like it when your first question is answered and then you morph your question into a completely new question.

Comment: stack overflow is meant to be Q&A.  Ask one question, get answer to that particular question, accept best answer, then done.  If another question comes out of that, then ask a new question.  This is not meant to be an ongoing discussion where you keep exposing more and more questions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your problem (just as you commented):

```
function InitSystems(socket){
  socket.write("Message 1: Hi!");
  socket.end();

  //After 2nd request from client
  socket.write("Message 2: Event has successfully taken place!"); //<-- Error here
  socket.end(); 
}
```

You are doing a `write()` after an `end()` is called, which you are not allowed to do. You can think of a socket as a wire connected between you (the server) and a client. As long as the socket is open you can send messages back and forth across the wire. Once you call `end()`, there wire is cut (socket is closed) and you can no longer send messages. Any attempt to do so will result in the error you are receiving.

Also noteworthy, JavaScript keeps executing after you call `socket.end()`, so your code above attempts to `write -> end -> write -> end` every time the function is called.  I'm not really sure what you are trying to acheive, but you shouldn't need to call `socket.end()` until you are completely done with the socket and no longer want to send any more messages.

If you want to conditionally write messages, you will need to keep some sort of state like this:

```
var reqCount = 0;
function InitSystems(socket){
    switch (reqCount) {
        case 0:
            socket.write("Message 1: Hi!");
            break;
        case 1:
            socket.write("Message 2: Event has successfully taken place!");
            break;
    }

    // You may want to do something to signify the end of a message
    socket.write('END OF MESSAGE');
    reqCount++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I tried but the error still persists. As in case 0 works as it is supposed to but I get the error again when case 1 executes

Comment: This still calls `.end()` which half closes the socket so it cannot be written to again.  This does not appear to be a solution.

Comment: Doh, thanks. Didn't read all of the code and assumed a the socket passed into the function would always be open. I've updated my answer.